# web2py Exception in sql rows

Tags: python, web2py

when i do the following code:

```
family_members =db(db.member.id == membership_id).select
(db.member.name,db.member.id)
family_members.colnames = ('Name','Membership ID')
```

It cause the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abeer/Desktop/web2py/New_version/web2py_src/web2py/gluon/
restricted.py", line 184, in restricted
  File "/home/abeer/Desktop/resources/web2py/New_version/web2py_src/
web2py/applications/init/views/default/updateMember.html", line 142,
in <module>
  File "/home/abeer/Desktop/web2py/New_version/web2py_src/web2py/gluon/
globals.py", line 112, in write
  File "/home/abeer/Desktop/web2py/New_version/web2py_src/web2py/gluon/
html.py", line 103, in xmlescape
  File "/home/abeer/Desktop/web2py/New_version/web2py_src/web2py/gluon/
sql.py", line 3326, in xml
  File "/home/abeer/Desktop/web2py/New_version/web2py_src/web2py/gluon/
sqlhtml.py", line 980, in __init__
  File "/home/abeer/Desktop/web2py/New_version/web2py_src/web2py/gluon/
sql.py", line 621, in __getattr__
  KeyError: '_extra'
```

P.S. : when i commented the line `(family_members.colnames = ('Name','Membership ID'))`, it works fine, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `colnames`. That attribute is internal to web2py. Use `db.table.field.label='..'` or `SQLTABLE(rows, headers={...})` depending on what you need.